# When was the guests' evacuation in Jurassic World?

Tags: plot-explanation, jurassic-world

After the attack of the flying reptiles in *Jurassic World*, the guests seem to dissapear from the park (as do the flying reptiles). They mention a cruiseship (or ships) will pick them up at first dawn. A bit later they say it will arrive in 45 minutes.

However, the Indominus Rex was drawn by the crowd, due to their huge heat profile (smell makes more sense to me though). Yet the crowd is nowhere to be seen, and they do not seem to be hiding in the buildings near the control center otherwise they would've been attacked by the raptors. Furthermore, the kids probably would have been evacuated as well if the guests were evacuated.

Then again after the final battle the systems are shut down, which seems to suggest that everyone is already gone, but then why aren't the kids also evacuated, and why are some people still on the island at all.

So I wonder where the guests were during the final battle, and why the Indominus Rex is not trying to reach them instead of the few individuals near the control center.

Comment: It could easily be that all guests could have been corralled into a dock holding area that might have some protection.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let us start at the beginning of the movie. This will provide context for what occurs later on, which is what you really asked about.

When the children get off the boat and step onto the pier, they are greeted by the site of a tram which takes them to the main concourse of the park:

[image]

---

They take this tram, you guessed it, to the main concourse. While there is no good, clear shot, this appears to arrive at the back end of the concourse as the very next scene shows passengers disembarking the tram and taking an escalator into one of the hotels.

[image]

This means that *the dock is not by the main concourse nor by the hotels where the epic dinosaur battle at the end of the movie takes place*.

---

At about 1:25 into the movie, a mob of park guests bust through a door from the main concourse into a back passageway, running from the remaining pterodactyls. *The crowd is leaving the main concourse where the final battle scene takes place*.

[image]

---

The children stay with Claire and Owen. During the Velociraptor chase, the children are in the back of the van that Claire is in, parked by the Velociraptor paddock. They do not evacuate with the rest of the crowd for whatever reason.

After the Velociraptor chase scene, we see that *everyone* is evacuating. The staff in the control center are evacuating: we see Dr. Wu being told to leave, and the other staff packing up and getting ready to go.

---

The park guests appear to have been herded somewhere else:

[image]

While it is not very clear, this looks like it could be where the children got off the tram earlier and went into the hotel. There is a tram loading dock next to a very tall building that is likely to be a hotel.

This is also where we hear the announcement about the next ship leaving in 45 minutes.

This shot is clearly at night or at least evening, and occurs *after* the Velociraptor chase: even if some guests were evacuated, there were still quite a few left as the dinosaurs were making their way back to the main concourse.

---

Next, we see what appears to be a shot of somewhere inside, perhaps the foyer of a hotel. Looking carefully, there is a zig-zag wall on the right which matches the zig-zag exterior wall in the shot above. This seems to indicate that the guests are in the entrance of the hotel, waiting to take the tram to the dock. They are likely waiting until the ship arrives in order to avoid being out in the open with vicious carnivorous dinosaurs on the loose.

[image]

---

Based on the sequence of events, it appears that as soon as the pterodactyls attacked that the guests were being evacuated. However, that many people cannot fit on one or even two ships: it took multiple ships and multiple trips.

Yes, the Indominus Rex *and* the Velociraptors were loose during the evacuation and the crowd was not yet evacuated: basic logistics says there is not much to be done about that other than to try to get those ships going as quickly as possible and to contain the loose dinosaurs as quickly as possible.

However, there are two *very* important things to keep in mind about what the dinosaurs are up to and how the humans are reacting:

- The two park leaders are both dead at this point, and everyone else is fleeing for their lives. While Owen and friends are surely concerned about saving any lives they can, there is not exactly anybody around to "think of the children" so to speak. The crowds are mostly on their way, although clearly some park staff are looking after them. Everyone has to leave on the ships anyway, so the staff may as well do what they can to help the crowds in the mean time.
- One would expect the Indominus Rex and the Velociraptors to take advantage of any opportunity (meal) that presents itself. However, they already have their quarry: Owen, Claire, and the children. Essentially, the dinosaurs are on the hunt for whomever was there during the initial attack on Indominus as well as any other scents they picked up during the ensuing chase (i.e. Claire and the children in the van).

  It would not make sense for the dinosaurs to go after the crowd, even if they are sitting ducks: they have a score to settle, and the crowd is not within sight or smelling distance.

---

Once the fight is over, there are lot of guests recovering in what appears to be a hangar on the mainland (soldiers are keeping guard) the next morning. Clearly, a large number of guests must have been evacuated during the night.

[image]

---

Finally, one little nitpick. The control center is not on the main concourse. The research labs were, but the control center is a short distance away as this shot of Ms. T. Rex greeting the sunrise with some jaw stretching shows:

[image]

She is standing on top of the roof of the control center, on the helipad, looking toward the main concourse; we can see the hotels and other buildings in the distance.

---

<sup>All screen shots are from the Blu-ray release of the movie. They are copyrighted by [Universal Entertainment](https://www.universalhidef.com/) and used here under the [fair use provision](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/107) of the U.S. Code.</sup>

Comment: Very nice answer :D
A nitpick from me would be that they are within smelling distance for the Indominus since it traveled over the whole island to get closer to the guests, that was the main problem.
Nevertheless, this seems to answer my question.

Comment: http://www.jurassicworld.com/park-map/

Answer (score 3):

I think the people get evacuated some time between when the "birds" attack and when the kids return to the city. If you remember it was still day when the aviary was broken and the "birds" attacked. Owen and the other security members manage to tranquillize them and then the kids insisted that they stay with Owen.

> **Gray:** Can we stay with you? 
>  
>  **Claire:** I am never leaving you again! 
>  
>  **Gray, Zach:** *[points to Owen]* No, no, him. We mean him.

When the hunt for Indominus started it was already night time, so there was enough time to evacuate the island. So either the island was evacuated and that's why Indominus went after them or the raptors were after Owen which in term led Indominus (part raptor) to them.

Comment: But they specifically say the boats will be there at first dawn, which is the next day...

Comment: Then the people were still on the island just not near the fight scene. Indominus hunts for sport, it is said in the movie, and sees Owen as his next challange. More so as he is part raptor it seems natural that when the raptors aknowledge him as the Alpha he joins them in hunting the "hunters". In the movie a raptor reaches Owen first, maybe they are faster than Indominus.

Comment: I'm not sure whether they still are on the island, I would think a loud and warm evacuation would attract the raptors and/or the Indominus Rex. I don't think the Indominus Rex would think Owen is any special or a challenge at all.

Comment: I think Indominus sees everybody as a challenge, it even hunts the kids after they escape in the first place. A being that challenges him and tries to kill him would be even more of a challenge. And from it's behavior after it escapes we can assume that although it is heading to the tourists it does deviate from it's course to kill everything it encounters.

Comment: That could be, but it doesn't answer my question :)
Also I'm not sure whether he is looking for a challenge at all.

Comment: I know, I've also red some articles but there is no mention of the evacuation in either of them... Not even speculations.