# Why don't the visitors get moved into the hotel and visitors center?

Tags: plot-explanation, jurassic-world

In the movie *Jurassic World*, when things go south in the park, all the visitors are moved to the central square in front of the visitors' center.

They clearly show how the visitors are suffering the heat of the sun and how crowded the place is.

1. Why didn't the park managers moved the visitors in the safer and
   more comfortable hotel and (for the ones without a room or that
   couldn't fit in the common areas of the hotel) in the visitors'
   center?
2. Why don't the visitors hide in the visitors center when the
   dinosaurs break out?

I'd like to understand if I'm missing something obvious or if it's just a plot hole like many that have been spotted in the movie already.

Comment: Related - https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/35786/when-was-the-guests-evacuation-in-jurassic-world